# Booleanfield not saving to database

Tags: python, django

`I have tried a few different styles of saving in the view. None of them will save the booleanfield to the database (PostgreSQL). However, all of the things I have tried save the inlineformset with no problems. This is the simplest view I could write. I would like to note that using the if all() way wrapping the validation line a type error telling me my 'bool' is not iterable comes up. I feel like I'm missing something small here but cannot figure out where I am going wrong.

```
class SundayBoolAvailable(models.Model):
    teacher_id = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True,
                                   default='',
                                   related_name='teacher_bool_available_id')
    sunday_bool = models.BooleanField(null=False, default=True)


class SundayTime(models.Model):
    teacher_id_time = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True,
                                        default='',
                                        related_name='teacher_time_available_id')
    sun_from_hour = models.TimeField(choices=HOUR_CHOICES, null=True, blank=True)
    sun_to_hour = models.TimeField(choices=HOUR_CHOICES, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.teacher_id)

@login_required()
@teacher_required
def availability_update_view(request, pk, *args, **kwargs):
    sun_obj = get_object_or_404(MyUser, id=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        sun_bool = SundayBoolForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=sun_obj)
        sunday_formset = SundayInlineFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=sun_obj, prefix='id_sunday_formset')
        if sun_bool.is_valid() and sunday_formset.is_valid():
            sun_bool.save(commit=False)
            sunday_formset.save()
            messages.success(request, f'You have successfully updated your availability!')
            return redirect('teacher_profile')

    else:

        sun_bool = SundayBoolForm(instance=sun_obj)
        sunday_formset = SundayInlineFormSet(instance=sun_obj, prefix='id_sunday_formset')

    context = {
        'sun_bool': sun_bool, 'sunday_formset': sunday_formset
    }

    return render(request, 'appointment/availability_update_new.html', context)

class SundayBoolForm(forms.ModelForm):
    #    sunday_bool = forms.BooleanField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = SundayBoolAvailable
        fields = ['sunday_bool']

    #        widgets = {
    #            'sunday': forms.HiddenInput(),
    #        }
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SundayBoolForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['sunday_bool'].required = False


class SundayTimeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = SundayTime
        fields = ['sun_to_hour', 'sun_from_hour']


#        widgets = {
#            'sunday': forms.HiddenInput(),
#        }

SundayInlineFormSet = inlineformset_factory(MyUser, SundayTime, form=SundayTimeForm, extra=0,
                                            can_delete=True, min_num=0, validate_min=True, max_num=3, validate_max=True,
                                            fields=['sun_to_hour', 'sun_from_hour'])


{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Title</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/availability_update_new.css' %}">
    </head>
    <body>
    <input type="button" class="sun-not-available" value="Not Available Sunday" onclick="sunCheckOne(); sunHideShow()"
           id="sun-not-available">
    <form id="all-add-form" method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="sunday-all" id="sunday-all-id">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <legend class="bottom mb-4">Profiles Info</legend>
            <div class="sun-bool">
                {{ sun_bool.sunday_bool }}
            </div>
        </div>
        {{ sunday_formset.management_form }}
        {% for sun_form in sunday_formset %}
            {% for hidden in sun_form.hidden_fields %}
                {{ hidden }}
            {% endfor %}
            <div class="sun_time_slot_form">

                {{ sun_form }}

                <button class="delete-sun-form" type="button" id="delete-sun-btn" onclick=""> Delete This
                    Sunday
                    Timeslot
                </button>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
        <button id="add-sun-form" type="button" class="button">Add Other Sunday Times</button>

        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary"/>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/add_timeslot.js' %}"></script>

    </body>
    </html>
{% endblock content %}
```